# Authenticating and Authorizing REST APIs

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created an application in the developer portal in WSO2 and am trying to generate a token using this curl command:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64encoded clientId:clientSecrect>" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=alex&password=alex123&scope=somescope" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

But I get the below response:

```
180{"error_description":"A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: ClientId","error":"invalid_client"}
```

I have tried also the following command :

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64encoded clientId:clientSecrect>" -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=&client_secret=" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

But with no success, I can generate the token from the devportal no problem but while executing it does not recognize the client for some reason. Could someone tell me what might be the problem for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the client id and secret in the Authorization header. You need to base64 encode client id and secret.

```
curl -k -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password&username=Username&password=Password" -H "Authorization: Basic Base64(clientid:client_secret)"

curl -k -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin" -H "Authorization: Basic VjhZRVdfUldISURZb0hJSU5yOTczVEhqYnBnYTpyVGg4N1VhUERPdGFlN25GUFFLc1pCR2FJdm9h"
```

Comment: Sorry when I posted the question I forgot to post exactly how I am doing the command I am using the client Id and secret encoded but still getting the error.
This is the documentation where I got the command:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/authenticating-and-authorizing-rest-apis/

curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64encoded clientId:clientSecrect>" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=alex&password=alex123&scope=somescope" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda half solved it because it is still not giving me the desired behavior. In carbon port 9444 I added a user and assigned it roles to the application that I want the token and when executed the curl i got the token did the same thing for carbon but with port 9443 and it still displays as

```
180{"error_description":"A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: ClientId","error":"invalid_client"}
```

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The following are the complete steps on registering an application in devportal, generating the client credentials, generating the access token, and using the access token to invoke the API calls. Please note that all these steps are achieved via the wso2am-3.2.0 devportal REST API calls.

WSO2 REST APIs are protected using OAuth2 and access control is achieved through scopes. Before you start invoking the API, you need to obtain an access token with the required scopes. This guide will walk you through the steps that you will need to follow to obtain an access token. First, you need to obtain the consumer key/secret key pair by calling the dynamic client registration (DCR) endpoint. You can add your preferred grant types to the payload. A Sample payload is shown below.

```
  {
  "callbackUrl":"www.google.lk",
  "clientName":"rest_api_devportal",
  "owner":"admin",
  "grantType":"client_credentials password refresh_token",
  "saasApp":true
  }
```

Create a file (payload.json) with the above sample payload, and use the cURL shown below to invoke the DCR endpoint. The authorization header of this should contain the base64 encoded admin username and password. Format of the request

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic Base64(admin_username:admin_password)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json https://<host>:<servlet_port>/client-registration/v0.17/register
```

Following is a sample response after invoking the above curl.

```
{
"clientId": "fOCi4vNJ59PpHucC2CAYfYuADdMa",
"clientName": "rest_api_store",
"callBackURL": "www.google.lk",
"clientSecret": "a4FwHlq0iCIKVs2MPIIDnepZnYMa",
"isSaasApplication": true,
"appOwner": "admin",
"jsonString": "{\"grant_types\":\"client_credentials password refresh_token\",\"redirect_uris\":\"www.google.lk\",\"client_name\":\"rest_api_devportal\"}",
"jsonAppAttribute": "{}",
"tokenType": null
}
```

Next, you must use the above client id and the secret to obtain the access token. We will be using the password grant type for this, you can use any grant type you desire. You also need to add the proper scope when getting the access token. All possible scopes for devportal REST API can be viewed in the OAuth2 Security section of this document and the scope for each resource is given in the authorization section of resource documentation. Following is the format of the request if you are using the password grant type.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<admin_username>&password=<admin_password>&scope=<scopes separated by space>" -H "Authorization: Basic base64(cliet_id:client_secret)" https://<host>:<gateway_port>/token
```

Shown below is a sample response to the above request.

```
{
"access_token": "e79bda48-3406-3178-acce-f6e4dbdcbb12",
"refresh_token": "a757795d-e69f-38b8-bd85-9aded677a97c",
"scope": "apim:subscribe apim:api_key",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600
}
```

Now you have a valid access token, which you can use to invoke an API. Navigate through the API descriptions to find the required API, obtain an access token as described above and invoke the API with the authentication header. If you use a different authentication mechanism, this process may change.

For further details please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#section/Authentication

Comment: I am using wso2am-4.0.0 devportal REST API calls will this solution still be applicable and maybe it was my fault for not specifying my situation from the begging which is that I have created an application in developer portal and have the consumer key and secret but when I execute a curl command to get access token it says :  curl -k -X POST https://is-as-km:9443/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password&username=Username&password=Password" -H "Authorization: Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret) " on port 9443 is says invalid client on port 9444 it gives the access token.

Comment: If you have not done any port offset to wso2am-4.0.0 you should have invoked the POST /token call on <APIM Server Hostname>:9443. But it seems that you are trying to invoke the POST /token on IS-KM:9443. Check your product, hostname, and port values. For APIM-4.0.0 refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v2/devportal-v2/#section/Authentication